# Wordpress 302 Temporary redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I need to temporarily move the directory of my site so I can drop in a landing page on the domain root. The landing page will live at a subdomain and point to the root domain (via DNS).

I am trying to do a simple 302 redirect via htaccess to change the directory of the site from https://example.com/ to https://example.com/home/, but I get stuck in a loop.
When I load the site I get this forever...

https://example.com/home/home/home/home/home/home/

Any ideas how to get this to work?

```
Redirect 302 / https://example.com/home/


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You don't appear to be moving the "directory of your site", you are just moving the homepage to a new URL - is that correct? However, if you redirect the homepage, how are you going to "drop in a landing page"? Presumably you will remove the redirect at that point?

Comment: What do you mean by "via DNS" exactly? Are you using a second domain (or subdomain) for this??

Comment: Yes not moving the site - just need the url to change. We are dropping in a landing page via a subdomain/dns which will point to example.com, so now we need the wordpress site to appear at example.com/home

Comment: Just curious, if you are implementing the landing page on an alternative hostname, then why do you need to redirect the existing homepage? They are different URLs.

Comment: the current site exists on example.com - we need the new landing page to exist on example.com - so something has to move....

Comment: So, the existing home page would need to move to the subdomain?

Comment: no. the landing page has been built separately from the main wordpress site. it was suggested that dns be changed to point the domain to this new landing page. if this occurs, their will be no way to access the main wordpress site so we need to move it or change the url somehow. Someone mentioned a 302 redirect was the solution but it isn't working.

Comment: "it was suggested that dns be changed to point the domain to this new landing page." - Presumably you mean point the "subdomain" to the new landing page? The main domain is already pointing to the root and cannot be changed. Although if you have a subdomain and a domain then it's creating a rather disjointed site?

Comment: So, what are the absolute URLs expected to be for the new landing page and existing WP homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So, the same directive will redirect `/home/` (which matches `/`) to `/home/home/` (`home/` is appended on the target), etc. etc.

Since you are already using mod_rewrite in the WordPress code block, you should also use mod_rewrite here also to avoid potential conflicts. mod_rewrite always executes before mod_alias, regardless of the order of directives in `.htaccess`.

For example, to 302 redirect the root only then use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [R,L]
```

Obviously, this redirect will need to be removed when you implement the alternative landing page in the root.

> The landing page will live at a subdomain and point to the root domain (via DNS).

However, if you are implementing this "landing page" via a "subdomain" (as suggested in comments) then I'm not sure why you *need* to move the existing homepage since it exists on a different hostname. (?)

But implementing the new landing page on a subdomain (that presumably points to the main domains document root) is going to create a very disjointed site. The subdomain and the main domain are two different sites.

If you are wanting to create a new landing page (replacing the old homepage) outside of WordPress (on the same domain) then I don't see how you can implement a "redirect" from the old homepage to `/home/` since this will naturally redirect the new landing page - unless this is only "temporary" as you say, until the new landing page is implemented?

As far I can see, you would need to:

1. Create a new WP page for `/home/` with the existing content of the homepage. (The existing WP homepage will no longer be accessible.)
2. Create your new landing page in a separate subdirectory (which won't be visible in the URL) - or perhaps just a separate file (eg. `/new-landing-page.php`) if this is a relatively simple page.
3. Internally rewrite requests from the document root (that would otherwise display the WP home page) to the new-landing-page, and prevent the request being routed through WordPress.

   For example:

   ```
   # Rewrite requests for the homepage to the new landing page.
   RewriteRule ^$ new-site/new-landing-page.php [L]
   ```

   When `example.com/` is requested `example.com/new-site/new-landing-page.php` is served (no redirect). WP is bypassed. But `/<something>` is routed through WP in the usual way.

Comment: any attempt to add something like this results in an error page...
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: What is the redirect loop you are seeing now? Presumably, you've already changed the homepage URL in WordPress?

Comment: WordPress Address (URL) or SIte Address (URL) ?

Comment: Neither, you're not moving the entire site - just the homepage. You effectively need to create a new route `/home/` that looks the same as your existing homepage. You can then implement a new landing page (outside of WordPress) in the root and internally rewrite requests from the root to the new landing page. No DNS/subdomains. But you cannot then redirect the root to `/home/` once you implement the new landing page as you would naturally redirect the new landing page.

Comment: @lowercase I've updated my answer. (But what redirect were you seeing?)

Comment: I appreciate the comments here and it all makes sense but I feel like I have not expressed things clearly enough. Lets say you have a wordpress site and someone comes along and asks to put a landing page in FRONT of the old website - effectively making their new page the new 'front page'. So now we need the old site - and its old home page, to move somewhere else. Does that make sense? They can handle the new front page on their own server, and via DNS will take over the root domain. I then need to move the old site so it still works AFTER the new page at somewhere like /home.

Comment: I know this is very very common - a landing page goes out front and has a big button that says 'enter/continue to website', that points to the old website.